# Can adding entropy to a copyrighted spatial data make it a new dataset?

Tags: data, copyright

I have a dataset of building polygons that is copyrighted. Say I applied some random noise to every point in each polygon, is there a theoretical measure at which the initial dataset is no longer identifiable, and the dataset becomes a completely different dataset?

I'm not certain that the dataset would still be useful at this point, but I'm curious if there is a legal or ethical argument justifying this approach.

The data is originally from the Ordinance Survey of Ireland with the following statement "The actual polygons are extracted from OS Maps which are under licence".

Comment: What country are you in that allows the copyright of GIS data _(or facts)_? Letting users know that might help illicit a relevant response. Copyright laws vary given the jurisdiction.

Comment: I've updated my question. The data is from Ireland, I am in the USA.

Comment: Typically this is going to be covered by derived works law, which is almost completely subjective.

Answer (score 4):

**FIRST: All legal issues are complicated.  Copyright law seems especially so.  The actual controlling law for any particular issue can sometimes seem random, and is often counterintuitive.  Any time you get anywhere close to copyright law, at least something that's not well settled, ask a lawyer.**

A database -- compilation of factual information -- usually can't be copyrighted in the U.S.  The exceptions involve subjective judgments of creativity involved in the selection, arrangement and presentation of the data itself.  In the case of geodata, a good rule of thumb is that the map can have copyright, but the data behind it probably not.  [In the EU that's not true.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_Directive)

That means there's likely no copyright issue, even though the data in question is copyrighted in the EU, there's no issue in U.S. jurisdiction.

A more likely problem is the contractual stipulations put on your use of the data.  This has been the avenue companies like Lexis-Nexus, Westlaw, and the like have pursued.  These provisions are enforceable in a U.S. court.

Does this mean Ordnance Survey can slap a click-through license before allowing you to download data, and you're then bound to not redistribute the data on pain of lawsuit?  I have no idea.  But as for copyright, you're likely in the clear.

Here's a decent if long winded summary from a Florida State law school professor of the legal issues regarding copyright and databases (30 page pdf): http://www.law.fsu.edu/journals/lawreview/downloads/254/sanks.pdf